# COUNT DISTINCT(column) slows the query 20X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this **query** which works fine and is fast (about 1 seconds execution time):

```
SELECT COUNT(ticket) AS times_appears
    ,COUNT(LOGIN) AS number_of_accounts
    ,comment
FROM mt4_trades
WHERE COMMENT != ''
    AND CLOSE_TIME != '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY comment
ORDER BY times_appears DESC
```

but as soon as I change the second line to:

```
,COUNT(DISTINCT LOGIN) AS number_of_accounts
```

the query is slowing down **20X** times.
Is the `DISTINCT` so slow that affects the whole query or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you please comment bellow why you are downvoting? It will be helpful for me to understand what I did wrong here.

Comment: Can you please explain what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried analysing your query to see what's causing it?

Comment: Yes my question is that why DISTINCT slows down 20X times the query and if there is a workaround to fix that!

Comment: Yes the `DISTINCT` is causing it

Comment: no, what I mean is... is the DISTINCT causing it because.... you're missing an index? or something else? Have you run a profiler over it to be certain what exactly is going wrong? https://redmondmag.com/articles/2013/12/11/slow-running-sql-queries.aspx

Comment: Look at the different execution plans. I give you a hint, look for a sort operation. Perhaps you'll think about grouping your data.

Comment: You could take a look on execution plans of both query to understand why you've got such a difference. And you may also take a look here : https://www.periscope.io/blog/use-subqueries-to-count-distinct-50x-faster.html and here https://www.periscope.io/blog/count-distinct-in-mysql-postgres-sql-server-and-oracle.html

Comment: No I am not missing an index. I checked that. But if the problem was a missing index wouldn't the `COUNT` without `DISTINCT` be slow also?

Comment: here, result is not cleared that, you need ticket count login wise or comment wise as your own answer give the ticket count irrespective of login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that sometimes is better to use a subquery than `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`.
So this is my **query** which is 20X times faster than the one on my question:

```
SELECT COUNT(mtt.ticket) as times_appears
       --,COUNT(DISTINCT login) as number_of_accounts
       ,(SELECT COUNT(LOGIN) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT login FROM mt4_trades WHERE COMMENT=mtt.COMMENT AND CLOSE_TIME != '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' ) AS temp)AS number_of_accounts
       ,comment
FROM mt4_trades mtt
WHERE mtt.COMMENT != ''
AND mtt.CLOSE_TIME != '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY mtt.comment
ORDER BY times_appears DESC
```

**@Raphaël-Althau** Thanks for the helpful URL-hint

Answer (score 0):

```
---- tickt count, irrespective of login
Select   mtt.comment
        ,t.number_of_accounts
        ,Count(mtt.ticket) As times_appears
From    mt4_trades As mtt With (Nolock)
        Join
        (
            Select   t.comment
                    ,Count(t.login) As number_of_accounts
            From    (
                        Select  Distinct
                                 mtt.login
                                ,mtt.comment
                        From    mt4_trades As mtt With (Nolock)
                        Where   mtt.comment <> ''
                                And mtt.CLOSE_TIME <> '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                    ) As t
            Group By t.comment
        ) As mt On mtt.comment = t.comment
Where   mtt.comment <> ''
        And mtt.CLOSE_TIME <> '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
Group By mtt.comment
        ,t.number_of_accounts

---- tickt count with respect to login
Select   t.comment
        ,Count(t.ticket) As times_appears
        ,Count(t.login) As number_of_accounts
From    (
            Select  Distinct
                     mtt.ticket
                    ,mtt.login
                    ,mtt.comment
            From    mt4_trades As mtt With (Nolock)
            Where   mtt.comment <> ''
                    And mtt.CLOSE_TIME <> '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
        ) As t
Group By t.comment
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the second query return the same value for `times_appears` and `number_of_accounts`. My query returns the correct values(same as `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` but if you think that it can be improved let me know)